# Problem with classification using yolo darknet

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, yolo, darknet

I have trained my custom object detector, using yolo darknet, with 3 classes :

```
 - human (full body)
 - high visibility jacket (HVJ)
 - safety helmet
```

It work great! But I need to add a features :

```
 - if in the frame an human wears nothing (not HVJ/helmet), it is tracked with red box
 - if in the frame an human wears an HVJ, it is tracked with yellow box 
 - if in the frame an human wears an helment, it is tracked with yellow box
 - if in the frame an human wears an helmet and an HVJ, it is tracked with green box
```

How can I implement it? Currently with my trained model cannot do it.
I'm thinking that I could create a new dataset with the following classes and train the model again with the classes :

```
- human with nothing 
- human with only HVJ
- human with only helmet
- human with HSJ and helmet
```

But I am not convinced that this method can work. 
Can you give me some suggestions?
If it can be useful to know for the testing mode I use a script in python/OpenCV.

Comment: after you have a human detected with your current detector, you could try to classify that subimage with a 2nd model

Comment: This method will probably be slow and I need a real time method ...

Comment: classification is quite fast, but still migjt be a problem. Yolo can train multi-class, maybe just try your approach and add the detailed classes to tge existing ones.